# c++ changing number digits places?

Tags: c++

I have a 3 digit number, let's say n = 135. I need to change the digits in the number so that I get a different number. Putting first number in the middle for the result of 315. I figured first thing i have to do is extract separate digits and I went with this

```
int n = 135;  
int a, b, c, x;

a = n / 100;
b = n % 100 / 10;
c = n % 10;
```

Now I have separate digit values but no idea how to put them all together into one variable to get x = 315.

EDIT:
Figured it out after writing. Don't know how to mark post as solved without choosing an answer. Solved it like this (if someone else encounters same problem):

```
x = b * 10 + a;
x = x * 10 + c;
cout << "Changed number: " << x << endl;
```

Comment: How would you do it by hand if you needed to add `1`, `3` and `5` together and get `315`?

Comment: Convert the integer to string, manipulate the string and then convert it back to integer.

Comment: Was this a learning exercise, or are you trying to apply it in a more general sense?

Comment: FYI, it is allowed to answer your own questions

Comment: learning excercise and its solved already. one of those things when u go through some theory and an example program and get like 6 problems to solve on your own.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Multiplication is your friend.

```
x = b * 100 + a * 10 + c;
```

Answer (score 1):

So, alright.  The way I would do this, and please correct me if this doesn't work, would be to make it into a string, and then re-arrange stuff like that.  To do that, we could use the string formatting library like this:

```
string number = to_string(135);
```

Then, you could do stuff like this:

```
char swap;
swap = number[0];
number[0] = number[1];
number[1] = swap;
```

That'll swap the first and second items, making it 315.  The others follow logically.  After you're done, just convert the string back to an int, like this:

```
int number = atoi(number.c_str());
```

Comment: They guy just started working with C++.  While I'll admit a string is the way I would do it I feel this will be way over their head.

Comment: it might work. but the whole code is unfamiliar to me :D

Comment: Hm.. that's fair, @NathanOliver.  I just find that it's a huge ton easier with strings, and I used that technique the first time I learned it :)